# Android studio dependency error

Tags: dependencies, android-studio

I was using eclipse and I have imported my project to android studio. It was working fine for a few days then suddenly the error showing below comes up.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> dx is missing
```

build.gradle looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: It looks like something has gotten messed up with your Android SDK; have you been doing anything to it? Does it compile from the command line? Make sure you have the right path to it specified in Project Structure > Android SDK. If that looks okay then you could try reinstalling your SDK or perhaps Android Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `dx.jar` under the path

```
#YOUR_ANDROID_SDK\build-tools\19.0.X\lib
```

Check `dx.jar` in only the version which you are using in your project's `build.gradle` files. If its not there download the respective build tools again from your sdk manager and try.

Comment: What is the equivalent path in genymotion. Could not find build-tools?

Comment: Android Studio requires `build-tools` in order to compile and build the apps, If you haven't installed any install them from your SDK manager.